# Install Visual Studio 2015 community edition on Windows Embedded Standard 7

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-embedded, windows-embedded-standard

I tried to install Visual Studio 2015 community edition on an embedded PC with WES7 which we use in our machines. We used to do this with Visual Studio 2010 express edition without problems. Our code has been updated to use .NET 4.6 and some C# 6 features though.

The installation fails stating that it can't install Windows update KB2999226 (Universal CRT). When I take a look at the information on the Microsoft website it seems that this update is not applicable to WES7. However there is a forum post in which someone states he installed this package successfully.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9996036f-f7af-412a-98c4-0baf7dbe8009/installing-vc2015-runtime-on-windows-embedded-standard-7

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: I have this issue too. Im considering installing the vs 2010 pro trial instead. trying it tomorrow

Comment: Did you ever resolve this, as I am trying to get the VC++ 2015 on Windows Embedded Pro 8.1 and am having difficulties which you may already have overcome?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. We've switched to Visual Studio 2017 which doesn't have this problem.